# Async/await dart support on Chrome Dev Editor

Tags: asynchronous, dart, chrome-dev-editor

Dart recently added a support for async/await keywords:
https://www.dartlang.org/articles/await-async/

I tried to run a simple code but Chrome Dev Editor does not recognise async keyword

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
}
```

Am I doing something wrong (something to modify in the `pubspec.yaml` ?) or is it just that this feature is not supported yet on Chrome Dev Editor ?

**Edit:**

Ok, so for know it seem that async/await seems to be more an experimental feature:

https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#async-opt-in

> To opt into asynchrony support in Dart Editor, go to **Preferences**, click **Experimental**, and select **Enable Async Support**.
>
> In dart and dartanalyzer, use the --enable-async command-line flag:
>
> ```
> dart --enable-async async_await.dart
> dartanalyzer --enable-async async_await.dart
> ```

Unfortunatly, it seems only to work for Dart Editor, not CDE.

Also, dart does not currently support the conversion into javascript without adding a package:

```yml
dependencies:
  async_await:
    git: https://github.com/dart-lang/async_await.git
transformers:
- async_await
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So currently it's not supported.

Now there is an issue on this problem: https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/issues/3822

Thank you for all your answer

Wait & see...

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the async module?

From the page you linked:

> The features described in this article are still under development. Not all the parts of the system necessarily comply with the spec. Early adopters may need to import `dart:async` for these features to work. Ultimately, Future should move to dart:core and be universally available.

Comment: Yes I did an `import 'dart:async';` but it does not work (other fuctionalities and class from the async API works well)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my Chromebook right now (and can't verify), but I believe you have to enable it under experimental features in the settings.

Comment: I may be missing something but the setings of Chrome Dev Editor seem pretty limited. I didn't find anything.

Comment: My fault. I misread and thought you were talking about the Dart editor. The CDE probably doesn't have support for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this helps with CDE, but the Asynchrony part of the Dart language tour has some information on [opting in to asynchrony support](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#async-opt-in) for other tools.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortunatly, it seems to work only for Dart Editor, not CDE

Comment: Now that Dart 1.9 is out, asynchrony support is on everywhere.